# Can't find class org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Binder

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, jersey, tomcat8

I have an existing SOAP web service project, and I want to expand it so it supports RESTful services as well.

When I create an empty web project and follow instructions using tutorial found [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/restful/restful_first_application.htm), everything works just fine, but in my existing project I get an error `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Binder`. I've made sure to put all libraries in the WEB-INF folder and include them, just like I've done with a test project.

Here is part of my web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>XFireServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.codehaus.xfire.transport.http.XFireConfigurableServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>XFireServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>


<servlet> 
  <servlet-name>Jersey RESTful Application</servlet-name> 
  <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class> 
  <init-param> 
    <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name> 
    <param-value>com.rest</param-value> 
  </init-param> 
</servlet> 
<servlet-mapping> 
  <servlet-name>Jersey RESTful Application</servlet-name> 
  <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern> 
</servlet-mapping>
```

And here's my UserService class:

```
@Path("/UserService") 
public class UserService {
    User user = new User();

    @GET
    @Path("/users")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String getUsers() {
        return user.getHello();
    } 
}
```

I get an error when I try calling it with Postman with URL: http://localhost:8080/project/rest/UserService/users

I can't reproduce this in another project. I tried using the same libraries and same Java EE version (7.0), and it works just fine.